Please, help me access the return value of a function in Python
I am a Python novice, I have a question regarding accessing and using the return value of a function outside of the function.
Let's say I have a function like this:
r2 = ["1","2"]

def FunctionA():
    data = "3"
    return data



r = FunctionA()
print(r)


r2 = r2.append(r)

print(r2)

this piece of code returns:
3
None
I need to access "r" and do stuff with it. I don't understand why I can print r, but I cannot append it to r2. Is the value in "r" lost? How can I store it correctly so that I can pass it to other functions?
I can't figure it out.
I tried storing the return value in a variable and printing the variable.

append appends the element in place, modifying the list and returning None. In your code just change r2 = r2.append(r) to r2.append(r) If you cannot figure it out the best is to look at the documentation, which has some examples https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

str.append() returns None

The issue is that you override r2 with the return value of append.
The append method modifies the list in place and returns None. You should call append without assigning its result back to r2.
r2 = ["1", "2"]

def FunctionA():
    data = "3"
    return data

r = FunctionA()
print(r)

r2.append(r)
print(r2)```


you can try storing the return value of FunctionA() in r
r2 = ["1", "2"]

def FunctionA():
    data = "3"
    return data

r = FunctionA()
print(r)  

r2.append(r)  
print(r2)

or you can try like eliminating the need for a separate append() operation
def FunctionA():
    return "3"

r2 = ["1", "2", FunctionA()]

print(r2)

Give you
['1', '2', '3']


When you use 'append', you assign None to r2 because 'append' doesn't return the updated list.
Append the value of r to r2 without reassigning r2, like this:
r2.append(r)

